# Python - web scraping pubmed.gov abstracts w/ BeautifulSoup - getting nonetype error

Tags: python, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pubmed

I am web scraping abstracts from [pubmed.gov](https://pubmed.gov) and it's working for the most part, except for abstracts that have no text. I tried a IF statement, but I'm clearly not doing something right.  How can I do this and have it skip over urls without abstract text? I've provided a URL where this happens.

I'm getting this error:  *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'*

Thanks in advance!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

listofa_urls = ['https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31103571']

for th in listofa_urls:

    response = requests.get(th)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    if (soup.find(class_='abstr').find('div') is not None):
       div_ = soup.find(class_='abstr').find('div')
       if div_.find('h4'):
           h4_ = div_.find_all('h4')
           p_ = div_.find_all('p')
       else:
           h4_ = soup.find(class_='abstr').find_all('h3')
           p_ = soup.find(class_='abstr').find_all('p')

       mp = list(map(lambda x, y: [x.get_text(),y.get_text()], h4_, p_))
       print(mp)
```

Comment: Which line has the error? What happens if you `print(dir(soup))`?

Comment: I'm getting the error for:   if (soup.find(class_='abstr').find('div') is not None):

Comment: i do not see any tags with the `class = "abstr"` in the html source code, hence `.find('div')` will not work, because you can not use `.find()` when `(soup.find(class_='abstr')` isn't returning anything

Comment: @chitown88 As stated by the OP, this is exactly what it is wrong ! :) How can he deal with the case when `soup.find()` returns  `None`

Comment: ah ok, I see that now. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you cannot do `.find()` to None, so just check if the first `find` finds anything.

Just remove the second `find`:

```
if (soup.find(class_='abstr').find('div') is not None):
```

Becomes

```
if (soup.find(class_='abstr') is not None)
```

Comment: This could miss a hypothetical case in which a "class='abstr'" element is present but a "div" is not, in which it would throw the same "no attribute 'find'" error as before on the following line.  To account for that possibility then in addition to this answer I'd adjust the subsequent condition from "if div_.find('h4')" to "if div_ is not None and div_.find('h4')"

Comment: If I have Seen well, if there is an abstract, there is an h4. For this case I think this is not necessary. But for other sources you are completely right